# bone_capemgr missing in Linux 3.16.0-bone2 BeagleBoneBlack?

Tags: c, linux, embedded, kernel

I just installed linux 3.16.0-bone2 on my BBB from https://rcn-ee.net/deb/trusty-armhf/v3.16.0-bone2

Im used to work with dtbos and /sys/devices/bone_capemgr*/slots in Linux 3.8.x
So I was surprised to find it missing in 3.16

How do I load dtbos in 3.16?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

good news: it sounds like cape manager is gone...

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/beagleboard/ND3_w7_dn8Q

It sounds like you should include your cape dts in the bbb dts and just load it at boot time rather than overlay it at run time.